# How to adapt this wordpress loop query code to include pagination?

Tags: foreach, pagination, wordpress

I have sourced the below code to query my posts in Wordpress and all works as intended.

I'd like to add pagination to this now. I don't want to alter the code too much now that I know it works, can anyone advise on the best way to adapt this to include the pagination?

I would like it to show a maximum of `18 posts per page` and have `next` and `prev links` to other pages if they exist. This code is being used in custom category templates, but I have also setup a static page setup under the reading settings and the display of main posts uses home.php, I'd like to use the same or similar loop code to also paginate that. Any help is appreciated. Here is the code:

```
<div id="Items">
<ul>
<?php
// Grid sorted alphabetically
if (is_category('categoryName')) 
{
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 'category' => 41 );
$categoryNameposts = get_posts( $args ); 
}
foreach( $categoryNameposts as $post ) :    setup_postdata($post); 
?>
<li><?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div><!-- #ItemsEnd -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You should let wordpress know how much post you want to show per page in the query_posts. Replace your $args with these two lines:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 18, 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 'category' => 41 );
```

Now to show Next-Previous link:

```
<div class="paginationClass">
   <?php next_posts_link(); ?>
   <?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
</div>
```

Also in is_category function, use categorySlug, instead of categoryName.

Comment: Thank you Sufi, this limits the number of posts accurately but the next and previous links do not appear? If I type some standard text behind their closing tags then this displays on the page so I know where it should be located but nothing there? Any ideas?

Comment: @M.F did you put next-previous link part within the loop? You need to put it after endwhile and before endif.